# How to hide unselected items on a checkboxlist?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist which gets the data from XML file. If a user selects an item on checkboxlist, i just want to show that item and hide everything else. And beneath that, I want to add clickable text to let the use to choose something else. So if the use click on that text, the user will see the checkboxlist again with the first item selected.

Basically look like this. [image: exampe]
So how do we achieve this?

Thanks so much.

require to use vb.net/and checkboxlist control as we will be databinding dynamically from database.

Comment: I would do it all with jQuery. Much less overhead on the server and doesn't require any postback.

Comment: for people who don't have javascript supported, they'll see the entire checkbox list, you'll just have to do server side validation to make sure they don't check more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way. Use two Panels as container for two different CheckBoxLists. The first displays your "FROM"-Items and the latter your "TO"-Items.

The second panel is initially invisivle. Apart from the CheckBoxList it contains a LinkButton to trigger the deselection.

On `BtnSelect`-Click you'll add the selected items from the first to the second CheckBoxList and show it's Panel. On `BtnChangeSelection`-Click you only need to switch visibiliy of both Panels and select first item.

This already works with multiple selection.

ASPX (CSS is up to you):

```
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="PnlChkListAcademicYear" runat="server">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkListAcademicYear" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnSelect" Text="Select" runat= "server" ></asp:LinkButton>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:panel ID="PnlChkListAcademicYearActive" Visible="false" runat="server">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkListAcademicYearActive" Enabled="false" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnChangeSelection" Text="Change selection" runat= "server" ></asp:LinkButton>
    </asp:panel>
</div>
```

Codebehind:

```
Private Sub BtnSelect_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSelect.Click
    If Me.ChkListAcademicYear.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim selectedItems = (From item In Me.ChkListAcademicYear.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)() Where item.Selected).ToArray
        Me.ChkListAcademicYearActive.Items.Clear()
        Me.ChkListAcademicYearActive.Items.AddRange(selectedItems)
        Me.PnlChkListAcademicYearActive.Visible = True
        Me.PnlChkListAcademicYear.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BtnChangeSelection_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnChangeSelection.Click
    Me.ChkListAcademicYear.SelectedIndex = 0
    Me.PnlChkListAcademicYearActive.Visible = False
    Me.PnlChkListAcademicYear.Visible = True
End Sub
```

---

This is the rest of my sample-code, for the sake of completeness:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindCheckboxList()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BindCheckboxList()
    Me.ChkListAcademicYear.DataSource = GetData()
    Me.ChkListAcademicYear.DataTextField = "Year"
    Me.ChkListAcademicYear.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Function GetData() As DataTable
    Dim years = {"2010/2009", "2009/2008", "2008/2007", "2007/2006", "2006/2005", "2005/2004", "2004/2003"}
    Dim tbl = New DataTable
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Year"))
    For Each y In years
        tbl.Rows.Add(y)
    Next
    Return tbl
End Function
```

Comment: thanks Tim that's something I really wanted to do. There were few errors I had but I fixed them. Thanks.

Comment: @Laurence: Glad to hear that it works. But the above code works well standing alone, the errors are probabyly caused by integrating this into your other code.

Comment: Hi Tim, I got this Compilation, I am using xml datasource so not an urgent problem but for getting more knowledge, it's good to know & very much appreciated that u put that in the first place. **Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'Columns' is not a member of 'datatable'. Line 24: tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Year"))** I have System.Data namespace imported. Thankssss.

Comment: @Laurence: DataTable definitely has a [Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd.aspx) property ;) So there must be a NameSpace conflict or whatever problem. Ask another question for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend doing this entirely with jQuery. It's slick and quick.

**HTML**
<sub>*this wil be generated by your `<asp:CheckboxList />`, you don't have to worry about using it, it's just here for reference.*</sub>

```
<table id="checkboxWrapper">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check1" value="Item 1" /></td>
        <td><label for="check1">2010/2009</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check2" value="Item 2" /></td>
        <td><label for="check2">2009/2008</label><td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check3" value="Item 3" /></td>
        <td><label for="check3">2008/2007</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="check4" type="checkbox" name="check4" value="Item 4" /></td>
        <td><label for="check4">2007/2006</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <div id="CheckboxListInscructionPlaceholder" style="display:none;">
        <a id="ChangeSelection" href="#">Change Selection</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**
<sub>*this is what you'll add to your scripts in order to enable what you need.*</sub>

```
$('#checkboxWrapper  td > :checkbox').change(function() {
    // hide the checkboxes that are not Checked
    $('#checkboxWrapper td >  input:not(:checked)').hide()

    // hide the labels that correspond to the unchecked checkboxes
    $('#checkboxWrapper td >  label[for!="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').hide();

    // show the "Change Selection" link
    $('#CheckboxListInscructionPlaceholder').attr({
        style: 'display:block;'
    });

});

$('#ChangeSelection').click(function() {
    // uncheck all of the checkboxes
    $("#checkboxWrapper td > input").prop("checked", false);

    // show all of the checkboxes
    $('#checkboxWrapper td > input').show();

    // show all of the labels
    $('#checkboxWrapper td > label').show();

    // hide the "Change Selection" link
    $('#CheckboxListInscructionPlaceholder').attr({
        style: 'display:none;'
    });
});
```

[Here's a working jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rockinthesixstring/w7SWP/)

I haven't tested it on an `asp:Checkboxlist`, but this should work since I'm not using any hardcoded `id`'s.

Comment: Thanks so much Chase, it was really a nice example for me. Being able to do it in client side is very handy. But we more like to do it in server side. But really thanks alot.. really a good example of work.